# How to choose i-th element in enum object

Tags: c, enums

Is there a way to choose a specified i'th enum from my enum object?

For example:

```
enum keys_t = {P, Pv, Pr, Pd, U, I, S, proc, R, H, A, sqrt, plus, minus, mult, equal, none, error};
```

and now I would like to call element number i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `enum` does not assign numbers explicitly, you can cast `i` to `enum keys_t` to obtain the value:

```
enum keys_t ithValue = (enum keys_t)i;
```

Generally, though, there is no support for obtaining an `i`-th value when you assign them explicitly: you would need to build an array for that:

```
enum keys_t {P=2, Pv=3, Pr=5, Pd=7, U=11, I=13, S=17, proc=19, R=23, H=29, A=31, sqrt=37, plus=41, minus=43, mult=47, equal=53, none=0, error=59};
enum keys_t keyT_vals[] = {P, Pv, Pd, U, ...}; // ...and so on
...
enum keys_t ithValue = keyT_vals[i];
```

If you would like to obtain the name of i-th enum value, you need to create an array of strings, and maintain it separately from the enum. You can use "stringize" macro for that:

```
#define STR(x) #x

enum keys_t {P, one, error, ...};
char *keys_t_names[] = {STR(P), STR(one), STR(error), ...};
...
char *ithName = keys_t_names[i];
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/fBq78M)

Comment: Are you sure about the 1st approach? This fast example does not seem to work: `enum keys_t = {P, one, error};
    enum keys_t ithValue = (enum keys_t)1;
    printf("The value is %s\n", ithValue);
    return 0;`

Comment: @Noran C `enum` is an integral type, you cannot print it like a string or obtain its name. In fact, all enum names are gone by the time the compiler is done. The trick works for numeric values, though ([demo](http://ideone.com/5UoNzq)).